# Still using texlive 2017

Tags: texlive-2018

I've just upgraded to Texlive 2018 via dnf and my Tex installation no longer works, using kile as the frontend. It is trying to use Texlive 2017

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) we need more information: what operation system are you using? Kile is mostly used on Linux, exactly what did you install and how? Is Kile explicitly configured to use full path when it calls latex? If so, adjust it to the new page.

Comment: The Linux distros tend to be a little behind with TeX Live. I always install TL via the TUG DVD rather than dnf but you could try to adapt [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092) if you need the dependencies.

Comment: see if your `$PATH` variable is set accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed a similar problem by removing everything through

```
dnf remove texlive texlive* texlive-scheme-full texlive-collection-science kile
```

then

```
updatedb
```

Then

```
locate texmf
```

and remove every instance using `rm -rf` with real care. Especially, there may be a hidden directory - something like `\home\bob\.texlive2017`, visible via `ls -al`. Then `updatedb`, `reboot` and then install via `dnf` or the equivalent the sequence above.

Worked for me, though I suspect that the problem was the `.texlive2017` directory.